# How can I remove sp_addextendedproperty from a SQL Server view script?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcompare

I am doing a comparison of my Dev and QA databases. My Dev database has a bunch of sp_addextendedproperty information, which prevents the scripts from being an exact match. I tried dropping and recreating the offending view, but the noise is still there. How can I remove sp_addextendedproperty from a SQL Server 2008 R2 view script?

```
EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value = N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "apc"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 125
               Right = 236
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "p"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 274
               Bottom = 125
               Right = 459
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "a"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 497
               Bottom = 125
               Right = 669
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "ch"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 707
               Bottom = 95
               Right = 867
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "c"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 905
               Bottom = 125
               Right = 1065
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "r"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 96
               Left = 707
               Bottom = 185
               Right = 867
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
      Begin ColumnWidths = 9
         Width = 284
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500', @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = N'dbo', @level1type = N'VIEW', @level1name = N'vwAccountProfitCenters';
GO

EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_DiagramPane2', @value = N'
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 11
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 900
         Table = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
', @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = N'dbo', @level1type = N'VIEW', @level1name = N'vwAccountProfitCenters';
GO

EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value = 2, @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = N'dbo', @level1type = N'VIEW', @level1name = N'vwAccountProfitCenters';
GO
```

Comment: Did you try [`sp_dropextendedproperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178595(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL compare (v10 is the one I have), once you've done your table mappings, there is another tab called options.  On here under the ignore section is a tick box for extended properties, tick that and then it won't matter if there are different properties on each table.

As @Tarzan mentions [in a comment below:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903761/how-can-i-remove-sp-addextendedproperty-from-a-sql-server-view-script/57812240#comment20968821_14936094)

> Yes, from SSMS, go to "Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > scripting > Script extended properties = False".

Comment: Yes, from SSMS, go to "Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > scripting > Script extended properties = False".